# Kerberos authentication of Windows clients and Redhat 5.5 with Samba PDC?

Tags: windows-server-2003, samba, kerberos, rhel5, domain-controller

I already realize that configure `Redhat 5.5` as PDC (Primary Domain Controller), and the clients (`Windows XP` and `Windows 2003`) can join the realm. The realm name of Linux server is `EXAMPLE.COM`.

Currently, when the time client (e.g., `Windows 2003`) join `EXAMPLE.COM`, from the packet captured by the `Wireshark`, we learn that there is only NTLM packet in the dcerpc protocol, there is no kerberos packet. The conclusion is that the client is not executing kerberos authentication.
    My samba configuration file  smb.conf is as follow:

```
[global]
　　workgroup = SINF                    #my domain name
　　server string = Samba PDC Server        
　　netbios name = SAMBA149            #my host name 
　　local master = yes　　
　　preferred master = yes
　　domain master = yes
　　local master = yes
　　wins support = yes
　　os level = 100
　　domain logons = yes
　　logon drive = K:
　　logon script = startup.bat
　　time server = yes
　　admin users = root
　　logon path = \\%N\%U\profile
　　logon home = \\%N\%U 
　　log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
　　max log size = 50　　
　　security = user
　　passdb backend = tdbsam
　　
　　[netlogon]
　　comment = Network Logon Service
　　path = /winhome/netlogon
　　writable = no
　　write list = root
　　follow symlinks = yes
　　guest ok = yes

　　[homes]
　　comment = Home Directiories
　　browseable = no
　　writable = yes
      create mode = 0664
　　directory mode = 0775
　　
　　[project]
　　comment = smbuser's project
　　path = /home/samba/project
　　browseable = yes
　　writeable = yes
　　write list = @users
```

Next, I want execution of the kerberos authentication when the client join the PDC, how can I realize it?
Any help would be appreciate sincerely! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The concept of a PDC has been outdated since the release of windows server 2003.  You are likely to find more information if you simply call it a domain controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me! As I checked from the internet, from the begining of Microsoft Windows 2000, there is no longer distinguish between the PDC and the BDC, all domain controllers are all in a equivalent position. One domain controller changes will be replicated to other domain controllers. We called it PDC Emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at his: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO

To be honest, the reason why kerberos is not used is a bit complicated to say the least.
Here's a quick checklist from the top of my head:

1. Are the clients configured to use kerberos? They might fall back to NTLM when kerberos does not succeed.
2. Do you have kerberos configured on the PDC? If not, samba is not able to use kerberos auth.
3. Are the clocks in sync between PDC and the clients? Kerberos is a picky about time.
4. Are you able to successfully get kerberos credentials by using kinit? If not, you haven't configured kerberos at all.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Relay on your advie, I check my configure:

Comment: I have reconfigured my samba and kerberos refer to the document from you. Now, The windows client(window2003) can execute the kerberos authentication when it joined the samba PDC. But, It occurs the “STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED”packet through captured packet by wireshare. I have not find where the problem ? @John Wilcox

Comment: I have successfully configured, the client (windows2003) can join Samba domain of redhat5.5.Next, I want to do is how to get the keys and tickets from kerberos authentication in the samba source code. There are still many issues to address Thank you very much! @John Wilcox